# Suggest me some LDAP hosting provider

Tags: ldap, hosting

as understood by the title, i really want to use LDAP authenticate for my private web projects.But unfortunately, i'm not a sysadmin guy and don't have as much time as i want, to try them all. 
What you would recommend me for ldap hosting - for small size company, with easy administration, not the cheapest but and not too expensive, and most important - securely.
Does not mater what OS will be used, or what services. Amazon, Google Cloud, Azure or new linux vps.
Thanks!

Comment: https://jumpcloud.com/blog/uncategorized/how-to-connect-your-application-to-ldap/ and https://aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/

Comment: jumpcloud look very nice, but i don't found a way to use my own domain for ldap. That's really confusing for me. For amazon i have nothing to say. :) Thanks very much for ur comment.

Comment: After some testing, i really like jumpcloud. After combining with G Suite look very nice and shiny. @jwilleke thank for your comment.